# JavaScript- How do I return the character at that index without using charAt method

Tags: javascript, string

I have a function that accept two parameters string and index. How do I write a code that will return the character at that index without using javascript built in method charAt. 
for e.g getIndex(great, 1) should return r

Comment: Or `str[idx]` ??

Comment: What code did you try? Read these topics in the [StackOverflow help section](https://StackOverflow.com/help): "How to ask homework questions",  "How to ask", and "Minimal Verifiable Example". This question does not meet the standards required or the guidelines StackOverflow was designed to handle.   What code did you try? What was the result of that code? How does your result differ from the expected result. Also, proofreading and proper grammar are expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work for you:

```js
getIndex = (str, index) => str.split('')[index];
console.log(getIndex("foobar", 3));
```

This may also be of interest:

```js
String.prototype.getIndex = function(idx) {
  return this.split('')[idx];
}
console.log("foobar".getIndex(3));
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

Create the function as below:

```
function getIndex(input, i) {
    return input.substring(i, i+1);
}

getIndex("great", 1)
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this:

```js
$('#show').click(function(){
  var string = $('#string').html();
  var position = $('#position').val() - 1;
  var result = string[position];
  $('#result').html(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='string'>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</span><br/>
<input type='text' id='position' value='5'> = 
<span id="result"></span>
<br/>
<button id='show'>DISPLAY RESULT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function getIndex(text, i) {
        return text.slice(i,i+1);
    }

    console.log(getIndex('great', 1));  // --> r
```

Comment: Add more details to your code so that OP can able to understand or in context with your answer.