# JavaScript charAt problem that I can’t seem to answer correctly

Tags: javascript

Write a function called charAt which accepts a string and an index (number) and returns the character at that index.

The function should return an empty string if the number is greater than the length of the string.

Do not use the built in charAt method - the tests will fail if you do!

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Would you please provide us the code you've written?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript- How do I return the character at that index without using charAt method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54917132/javascript-how-do-i-return-the-character-at-that-index-without-using-charat-met)

Comment: What code did you try? Read these topics in the [StackOverflow help section](https://StackOverflow.com/help): &quot;How to ask homework questions&quot;,  &quot;How to ask&quot;, and &quot;Minimal Verifiable Example&quot;. This question does not meet the standards required or the guidelines StackOverflow was designed to handle.   What code did you try? What was the result of that code? How does your result differ from the expected result. Also, proofreading and proper grammar are expected.

Answer (score -1):

```
function charAt(input, i) {
    return input.slice(i, i+1);
}
```

Comment: Marked down for being correct? Why not mark it as the accepted answer?